# The first click of the KSP re-root tool, what does it do?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

In Kerbal Space Program for the reroot tool, I know you click a part, then click another part and the second click is the new root.

What is the first click for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just have a big ship that you want to change the root part, the first click does nothing useful. You can click anywhere on your ship and on the second click select what you want as the new root.

If you detach any part of you ship, to make it ghosted out - or indeed drag a subassembly on but dont attach it to your ship it is also ghosted out. In this state, the first click of the reroot can be on your ghosted subassembly, and the second click is where you'd like to attach it to your ship.

Comment: so the first click picks the craft, and the second sets the root, that finally makes sense